# How to solve installation error, while installing tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I got an error while installing tomcat 7. I have searched for it, but couldn't find any solutions.

```
The error is..

  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package tomcat 7

Please help me...
```

Comment: provide all the steps followed and commands executed

Comment: first i did sudo apt-get install tomcat7. I got following error.  Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7 [fail] invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "start" failed.

Comment: then doing some terminal operation to edit source.list file then i got current error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error occured whilw installing tomcat7 in ubuntu14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115896/error-occured-whilw-installing-tomcat7-in-ubuntu14-04)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you have a space between `tomcat` and `7`. Use the following command to install tomcat7: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

**[Update]**
 1. Add `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe` to /etc/apt/sources.list file.
 2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
 3. Run `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` ?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing now? 
Did you install it already? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep tomcat` ? 

What is `sudo service tomcat7 status` saying?

Comment: dpkg -l | grep tomcat had no output. sudo service tomcat7 status shows tomcat7: unrecognized service

Comment: So, tomcat7 is not installed yet and what is the complete output of `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` ?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tomcat7

Comment: I have provided an update to the answer. You can try those 3 steps.

Answer (score 5):

As of now (5-5-2019) use 8 instead of  7.
sudo apt-get install tomcat8

Comment: what if I need specifically the tomcat7 version to be installed?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the latest tomcat version - tomcat9: "sudo apt install  tomcat9"